# Why I get error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error:

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to read a simple image from a directory, I am using openCV(4.2.0) with simple 2 lines:

`im = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\khand\OneDrive\Desktop\Thesis\Case_db\or\case_9-14000-12000-16000-14000-1-100-S')
cv2.imshow('im',im)`

How ever I get error like this:

> error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

I can read files images using PIL library, which means images are proper and readable. I need to use **cv::findContours(),**  that's why I need to open them in opencv. If anyone has any solution please feel free to help.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you check the path you are mentioning to load image from your system

Comment: I used same path for load images using PIL.Image.open(), that's why i think path shouldn't be a problem but lemme check again

Comment: And can you also check the shape of im array which is being loaded

Comment: I checked path, imread() is working and shape is 200 200, but still have the same problem in the line imshow()

Comment: Generally when the path is not right in imread function, it does not throw error instead it returns 'NoneType' object

Comment: Try using extension like '.jpg' or '.png' in path given to imread

Comment: thanks, problem solved but when shows image it doesn't fit to the window size, anyway I have to deal with it in some other manner, I need to find center of the objects in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
im = cv2.imread('C:/Users/khand/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/Case_db/or/case_9-14000-12000-16000-14000-1-100-S')
```

And specify the file extension, also make sure the file isn't used by other processes.

Comment: Yeah, I solved like that
im = cv2.imread('C:/Users/khand/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/Case_db/or/case_9-14000-12000-16000-14000-1-100-S.jpg')

Answer (score 1):

Loads an image from a file.

The function `imread` loads an image from the specified file and returns it. If the image cannot be read (because of the missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).

Currently, the following file formats are supported:

Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Note section)
JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Note section)
Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Note section)
WebP - *.webp (see the Note section)
Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm *.pxm, *.pnm (always supported)
PFM files - *.pfm (see the Note section)
Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Note section)
OpenEXR Image files - *.exr (see the Note section)
Radiance HDR - *.hdr, *.pic (always supported)
Raster and Vector geospatial data supported by GDAL (see the Note section)

TRY PIL or medpy

```
from medpy.io import load

image_data,image_header = load(path)
```

OR
You can also try pickle library also to load or read the data